# Is it okay to use thread.sleep() when coding a bot?

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a primitive spammer. Is it okay to use thread.sleep() when coding a bot?

I'm a novice programmer. If there is any place in my code to fix it, I would appreciate it if you let me know. I may have used JComponents improperly. If it catches your eye, you can specify. Thank you.

Note: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." I'm writing this note because I can't find any more details to add. Sorry

---

```
public class Spammer extends JFrame implements Runnable{
    
    private boolean running = false;
    
    private JButton jButton1;
    private JLabel jLabel1, jLabel2;
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private JSpinner jSpinner1;
    private JTextArea jTextArea1;
    
    public Spammer() {
        setLayout(null);
        
        jLabel1 = new JLabel("Text: ");
        jTextArea1 = new JTextArea(10,28);
        jLabel2 = new JLabel("Interval: "); 
        jSpinner1 = new JSpinner();
        jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
        jButton1 = new JButton("Spam");
        
        jButton1.setSize(350, 60);
        jButton1.setLocation(100, 220);
        
        jLabel1.setSize(50, 150);
        jLabel1.setLocation(15, 10);
        jLabel1.setFont(new Font("Verdana" , Font.BOLD , 14));
        
        jTextArea1.setSize(350, 150);
        jTextArea1.setLocation(100, 10);
        
        jLabel2.setSize(80, 25);
        jLabel2.setLocation(15, 180);
        jLabel2.setFont(new Font("Verdana" , Font.BOLD , 12));
        
        jSpinner1.setSize(350, 25);
        jSpinner1.setLocation(100, 180);
        
        
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
        getContentPane().add(jTextArea1);
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2);
        getContentPane().add(jSpinner1);
        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1);
        getContentPane().add(jButton1);
        
        setTitle("Spammer by Me");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 340));
        pack();
        
        jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                  jButton1ActionPerformed();
              } 
            } );
        
        
    }
    
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed() {
        if(!running) {
            jTextArea1.setEnabled(false);
            jSpinner1.setEnabled(false);
            jButton1.setText("Spamming in 3 seconds...");
            jButton1.setEnabled(false); 
            running = true;
            new Thread(this).start();
        }else {
            jTextArea1.setEnabled(true);
            jSpinner1.setEnabled(true);
            jButton1.setText("Spam");
            running = false;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Spammer().setVisible(true);
                
            }

        });
    }
    
    public void run() {
        Robot robot = null;
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        int[] keys = new int[jTextArea1.getText().length()];
        if((int) jSpinner1.getValue() < 0) {
            jSpinner1.setValue((int) 0);
        }
        int interval = (int) jSpinner1.getValue();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < keys.length; i++) {
            keys[i] = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(jTextArea1.getText().charAt(i));
        }
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        jButton1.setEnabled(true);
        jButton1.setText("Stop");
        
        while(running) {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < keys.length; i++) {
                robot.keyPress(keys[i]);
                robot.keyRelease(keys[i]);
                
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(interval);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't sleep on the EDT, and you shouldn't manipulate UI elements on a thread other than the EDT (what you're doing right now), other than that, this is asking for opinions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel They aren't sleeping in the EDT, but they are accessing GUI stuff from a non-EDT thread.

Comment: @rzwitserloot The _"(what you're doing right now)"_ applies to the second part, the first part was to be complete, but maybe I should have put it second for clarity.

Comment: @rzwitserloot "they are accessing GUI stuff from a non-EDT thread." Is it a problem?

Comment: It is almost always a mistake to use a null LayoutManager. Please remember that LayoutManager's are designed to help developers.

Comment: @NomadMaker I realize it works for quick experiments. But I want to design the design myself. I could not find a layoutmanager that can do the design on the screen. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: there will probably be a `NullPointerException` if the `Robot` cannot be created (`AWTException`)... better exit the `run` method in that case, or change `running` to `false`

Comment: How can robot cannot be created? if there is such a possibility How can I better exit the run method in that case,

Comment: While a GridBagLayout might manage it, I usually use multiple nested panels, each with their own LayoutManager. It may sound complicated, but it usually only takes me an hour or so to layout a complex panel.

Answer (score 2):

The key principle at work here is primarily the 'EDT' - the Event Dispatch Thread. This is a thread that does GUI stuff - if for example you drag the titlebar of a completely different app's window across the screen, and this moves that app's window over yours, the EDT is hard at work redrawing everything. The EDT is the thread that sees you press your mouse down on a button, and will render the button in the 'pressed in' view.

The EDT is **the only thread** from which you can do GUI stuff, whether it is to retrieve info, such as `getText()`, or whether it is to change things, such as updating the text of a label or whatnot.

The EDT is also the thread you're in when your code runs that you registered as a handler for events, such as the code that responds to a button click or whatnot.

You therefore **must not** sleep on the EDT (Because then your app looks non-responsive; the thread that responds to button clicks or repaints what needs repainting is not actively running), but you can only fetch GUI data / set GUI stuff from the EDT.

The rules:

- Do not interact with any GUI elements unless you are in the EDT
- Never sleep in the EDT

Your code is broken, not because you sleep (that's fine - that `run()` method is not in the EDT), but because you do GUI stuff from this non-EDT thread.

You need to do a careful dance here: You want to sleep (not allowed on the EDT), but interact with GUI elements, such as the interval box, to know how long to sleep, which can only be done on the EDT.

To do this, you can 'send' code to run in the EDT via SwingWorkers, or simply via:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
   // code that will run in the EDT goes here
});
```

You can't set any variables from within this code, but you can use `AtomicReference` and friends to create objects you can change. So, instead of:

```
int[] keys = new int[jTextArea1.getText().length()];
if (jSpinner1.getValue() < 0) {
    jSpinner1.setValue(0);
}
int interval = (int) jSpinner1.getValue();
```

which is doing GUI stuff, do:

```
AtomicInteger interval = new AtomicInteger();
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
  int[] keys = new int[jTextArea1.getText().length()];
  if (jSpinner1.getValue() < 0) {
      jSpinner1.setValue(0);
  }
  interval.set((int) jSpinner1.getValue());
};
```

Comment: For example I should use two invokeandwait in this code right?( One more for jButton1.setEnabled(true); jButton1.setText("Stop"); )

Comment: I need to create keys array outside of invokeandwait. (I am writing int[] keys;) And then Inside invokeandwait, I write the that code: keys = new int[jTextArea1.getText().length()];      
                                                                                                                                       
But that code line has a issue: But that code line has a issue: "Local variable keys defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"    Can you help for solve this?

Comment: Whatever you need to create, you can stuff inside an `AtomicReference`. You can't use `=`; but `someAtomicRef.set();` _is_ okay, and boils down to the same thing.

Comment: I converted the "keys" to an AtomicIntegerArray. But it still has "Local variable keys defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final" issue

Comment: Don't use `=`, use `.set`. Read the javadocs of `AtomicReference` and co. At this point you seem to be asking for me to just write it all out for you; SO is not that kind of site.

Comment: Actualy I tried to find a solution I've already used ".set" but still i have the error. but I will keep looking for a solution. Thanks for all help.

Comment: and as far as I understand:
we need to use robot.delay () since using thread.sleep () does not sleep exactly as much as we want.